# Not notify Fragment when remote Realm (on Realm Object Server) was changed

Tags: android, realm

When I start Android app I login to Realm Object Server and download (sync) data from Realm Server Object.
OK.
Now I got to Fragment that show list of persons.

Here code:

```
public class PersonsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView notEmptytsListView;
    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<Person> personsRealmResults;
    private PersonsAdapter personsAdapter; // RealmBaseAdapter<Organization>
    private RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.persons_fragment, container, false);
        init(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void init(View view) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        notEmptytsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.notEmptytsListView);
        personsRealmResults = realm.where(Person.class).findAllSorted(Person.NAME);
        personsAdapter = new PersonsAdapter(personsRealmResults);
        notEmptytsListView.setAdapter(personsAdapter);

        // NOT CALL WHEN DATA ON REALM OBJECT SERVER WAS CHANGED
       realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Object object) {
                personsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        personsRealmResults.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

If I stay on Fragment and data changed on Realm Object Server (remote Realm) the local data is not sync. Not call method onChanged().

How I can fix this?

Comment: Some of your code are not formatted, please proof-read.

Comment: You need to store RealmResults as field variable, not just local variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {    
    RealmResults<Person> personsRealmResults; // <--

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.persons_fragment, container, false);
        notEmptytsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.notEmptytsListView);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        personsRealmResults = realm.where(Person.class).findAllSorted(Person.NAME);
        personsAdapter = new PersonsAdapter(personsRealmResults);
        notEmptytsListView.setAdapter(personsAdapter);

        realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Object object) {
              // call when data on Realm Object Server was changed
         }
        };
        personsRealmResults.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Although it'd probably be easier if `PersonsAdapter` was a [`RealmBaseAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters). (see [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters))

Comment: It is. Here my adapter : `public class PersonssAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Person> implements ListAdapter`

Comment: Not help. Same result. Not call *onChange()*. See my updated code on post. Data change local only after I restart my application.

Comment: The above code should work, so something else must not be right. Are you 100% the changes are downloaded?

Comment: I found solution. When I create SyncConfiguration I must use "waitForInitialRemoteData". Here code: `SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, realmURL)
                .waitForInitialRemoteData()
                .build();`. And as result when remote Realm changed, my fragment is notified.