# Android, Realm: PermissionOfferResponse onChange() call only once

Tags: android, realm

When start Android app I want to:

- Login to Realm Object Server
- The receiver creates a PermissionOfferResponse
- Wait for the offer response to be synced and processed by the server, which will populate the realmUrl property of the response object.

Here code:

```
public class MainApp extends MultiDexApplication {

 private void loginAndConfig() {

String authUrl = "http://" + BuildConfig.OBJECT_SERVER_IP + ":" + BuildConfig.OBJECT_SERVER_PORT + "/auth";
    SyncUser.Callback callback = new SyncUser.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
            setPermissions(user);
        }


    SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(
            BuildConfig.USER_NAME, BuildConfig.PASSWORD, false);
    SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCredentials, authUrl, callback);
}

private void setPermissions(final SyncUser syncUser) {
    Realm managementRealm = syncUser.getManagementRealm();
    String offerToken = BuildConfig.REALM_OFFER_TOKEN;
    final PermissionOfferResponse permissionOfferResponse = new PermissionOfferResponse(offerToken);
    // Add to management Realm to sync with ROS
    managementRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.insert(permissionOfferResponse); 
        }
    });


    RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> realmResultPermissionOfferResponse = managementRealm.where(PermissionOfferResponse.class)
            //.equalTo("id", offerId)
            .equalTo("statusCode", 0) // status > 0 is error
            .findAll();

    realmResultPermissionOfferResponse.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse>>()  {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> offers) { 
            // call only once
            PermissionOfferResponse offer = offers.first();
            String realmURL = offer.getRealmUrl();
        }
    });
```

}

When I start app first time the method **onChange()** success call and as result I get *realmURL* from **PermissionOfferResponse**. OK.

But when I start app again the method **onChange()** NOT CALL. And as result I can't get RealmURL.

Comment: you can try using `findAllAsync()` instead

Comment: This seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713592/not-notify-fragment-when-remote-realm-on-realm-object-server-was-changed and they probably have the same underlying cause. My guess is that changes are not getting synchronized with the server for some reason.